# Blinking endscreen - pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So Im making a game and at the end of 60 seconds I want to make the screen change colors and display some end text.
I set up the timer like this:

```
time = 60
TICKTOCK = 0 
pygame.time.set_timer (TICKTOCK+1, 1000)
```

and that's being displayed onscreen just fine, but when the end screen appear it flashes between the original white screen and the end screen. For some reason, it doesn't flash if I'm waving my mouse around the screen.

```
if time <= 0:
     playground.fill(black)
     playground.blit(end, (0, 100))
```

"end" is my game over text variable

```
    pygame.display.flip()
    playground.fill(white)
    clock.tick (fps) 

pygame.quit()
```

This is what I have at the end too if that helps

Is there a way I can make it appear steadily without having to change my timer?

Comment: probably you have to change other parts of you code.

Comment: Is it because you're filling the background to white again? I have a feeling the fill function works without blitting it

Comment: why you `fill(white)` ?  probably you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show not enough code so I can only suggest to do something like this

```
if not gameover:

    playground.fill(...)

    # draw normal game

else:

    playground.fill(...)

    # draw gameover text

playground.flip()
```

Comment: This suggestion helped but I also found that changing my FPS or changing the timer from counting in seconds to milliseconds fixed it, thank you!

Comment: changing speed doesn't fix it - white screen still exist but now your eye can't see this white screen ;) on slower computer you will see white screen again :)